# LANG variable isn't overriden in testing environment

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, symfony-4.4

I'm working on a Symfony 4.4 project. The project has been created from scratch (it's not an update from a 3.4 codebase or something like that). I'm adding automated tests to my codebase, but I'm having problems with environment variables.

In my `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.test` and `.env.test.local` I have defined a `LANG` variable, to set the application language. To correctly test translations when I'm developing, in the `dev` environment (`.env.local` file) I've set `LANG=es`, and it's working correctly. In production it's also working correctly, but in test, in the `.env.test.local` file I've set `LANG=ca` but neither PHPUnit nor `bin/console debug:container --env-vars --env=test` show the correct value for this variable, it's value it's just `es_ES.UTF-8`, the value of the `$LANG` variable in my Ubuntu system.

I have other environment variables defined in the `.env.test.local` file, and these are correctly (like the `DATABASE_URL`). I've also tried to add the `LANG` in the `phpunit.xml.dist` file (`<env name="LANG" value="ca" />`), but it the value doesn't change, it's still `es_ES.UTF-8`.

I've also deleted the `var/cache/test` directory, but it still doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong? What can I do to change the language in the testing environment?

Comment: Could you test run your tests by passing $LANG=ca, for example `$LANG=ca ./bin/phpunit`? I have to confirm it but env variables of your system are the main used (top priority)

Comment: @qdequippe you are right: I've opened a new terminal, run `export LANG=ca` and then `bin/phpunit`, and the content of the site was in the correct language. Also, running `bin/console debug:container --env-vars --env=test` shows the correct language... Also, if I show the vars of the dev environment, the language is also `ca` (the one in the system) instead of `es`, the one in the `.env.local` file. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local

> Real environment variables always win over env vars created by any of the .env files.

Comment: Ok, so I have to rename my variable, isn't it?

Comment: yes or override it when you are using the console